# Conversion of URL for profile picture is not working

Tags: swift, eureka-forms, alamofireimage

I am currently trying to use [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) forms for my app.  I need to display a user profile, and then update it using AlamoFire from my website.  I want to be able to update profile information.  Using Eureka forms is extremely difficult, since I am relatively new to Swift programming, but it proves to be the most intuitive platform right now for quick development..

When I log into my website I can see my user profile picture, its stored as a path in my MySQL database.  My goal is to have my app do the same thing, view the picture and then change the picture with a picture from my phone and update the database.  I can take care of the PHP, but the code is where I am stuck.

As I mentioned, Eureka is extremely complex and I cannot figure out how to directly use AlamoFire to retrieve my information, so I was able to save it to NSDefaults, including the URL, but cannot figure out how to get it to display.  It keeps giving me a string error.  Here is the code:

**UserDataVC.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON 
import Eureka
import ImageRow

class UserDataVC:  FormViewController {


    let defaultValues = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    let parameters: Parameters=["id": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: 
"id_user")! ]

    let URL_USER_LOGIN = "https://www.mywebsite.com/userinfo.php"

    _ = Alamofire.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .get, parameters: 
parameters).responseJSON
        {response in
            print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // 
response serialization result

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: 
response.data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if let parseJSON = json {
                    let resultValue = parseJSON["errorcode"] as? String
                    print("result: \(String(describing: resultValue))")

                    var isUserInfoOk:Bool = false;
                    if(resultValue=="none"){ isUserInfoOk = true;}

                    var messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String!;
                    if(!isUserInfoOk)
                    {
                        messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String!;
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if isUserInfoOk == true{

                            //Display alert message with confirmation
                            if let result = response.result.value {
                                let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary

                                //if there is no error
                                if(!(jsonData.value(forKey: "error") as! 
Bool)){

                                    //getting the user from response
                                    let user = jsonData.value(forKey: 
"user") as! NSDictionary
                                    print(user)


                                    //getting user values
                                    let idUser = user.value(forKey: 
"id_user") as? Int
                                    let userFirstName = user.value(forKey: 
"first_name") as? String
                                    let userLastName = user.value(forKey: 
"last_name") as? String
                                    let userEmail = user.value(forKey: 
"email") as? String
                                    let userMobile = user.value(forKey: 
"mobile_number") as? String
                                    let userPicture = user.value(forKey: 
"profile_image_url") as? URL

                                    //saving user values to defaults
                                    self.defaultValues.set(idUser, forKey: 
"id_user")
                                    self.defaultValues.set(userFirstName, 
forKey: "first_name")
                                    self.defaultValues.set(userLastName, 
forKey: "last_name")
                                    self.defaultValues.set(userEmail, 
forKey: "email")
                                    self.defaultValues.set(userMobile, 
forKey: "mobile_number")
                                    self.defaultValues.set(userPicture, 
forKey: "profile_image_url")

                                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                                }
                            }

                        } else {

                            print("Error with user data")

                            // let myAlert = 
UIAlertController(title:"Error", message:messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: 
UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

                           // let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", 
style:UIAlertActionStyle.default) { action in
                            //    self.dismiss(animated: false, 
completion:nil);
                          //  }

                           // myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                            // self.present(myAlert, animated:false, 
completion:nil);

                        }
                    };
                }
            } catch let error {
                print("error occured \(error)")
                 }

    }

    form +++ Section("Your Profile")
        <<< UserInfoRow { row in
            row.value = User()
            row.reload()
    }


    form +++ Section("Edit Profile")
        <<< ImageRow() {
            $0.title = "Profile picture"
            $0.sourceTypes = [.PhotoLibrary, .SavedPhotosAlbum, .Camera]
            $0.clearAction = .no
            }

            .cellUpdate { cell, row in
                cell.accessoryView?.layer.cornerRadius = 17
                cell.accessoryView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, 
height: 34)
        }

     form +++ Section()
        <<< NameRow(){ row in
            row.title = "First name"
            row.placeholder = "Enter your First Name"
        }

        <<< NameRow(){ row in
            row.title = "Last name"
            row.placeholder = "Enter your last name"
        }
        <<< PhoneRow(){
            $0.title = "Mobile Number"
            $0.placeholder = "Enter your mobile number"
        }
        <<< EmailRow(){ row in
            row.title = "Email"
            row.placeholder = "Enter your email address"
        }
        <<< PasswordRow(){ row in
            row.title = "Password"
            row.placeholder = "Change your password"
        }

     form +++ Section()
        <<< ButtonRow() {row in
            row.title = "UPDATE PROFILE"

        }

//  let row: UserInfoRow? = form.rowBy(tag: "Your Profile")
    let valuesDictionary = form.values()





  }
}
```

and here is the next file

**UserInfoCell.swift**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage
import SwiftyJSON
import Eureka

final class UserInfoRow: Row<UserInfoCell>, RowType {
required init(tag: String?) {
    super.init(tag: tag)
    cellProvider = CellProvider<UserInfoCell>(nibName: "UserInfoCell")
}
}


final class UserInfoCell: Cell<User>, CellType {

@IBOutlet weak var userImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var firstnameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lastnameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mobileLabel: UILabel!


required init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func setup() {
    super.setup()

    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    // we do not want our cell to be selected in this case. If you use such 
a cell in a list then you might want to change this.
    selectionStyle = .none

    // configure our profile picture imageView
    userImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    userImageView.clipsToBounds = true

    // define fonts for our labels

    firstnameLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    lastnameLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    emailLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 13.3)
    mobileLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 13.3)

    // set the textColor for our labels
    for label in [mobileLabel, emailLabel, lastnameLabel, firstnameLabel] {
        label?.textColor = .gray
    }

    // specify the desired height for our cell
    height = { return 106 }

    // set a light background color for our cell
    backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.984, green:0.988, blue:0.976, 
alpha:1.00)
}

override func update() {
    super.update()

    // we do not want to show the default UITableViewCell's textLabel
    textLabel?.text = nil

    // get the value from our row
    guard let user = row.value else { return }

    // set the image to the userImageView. You might want to do this with 
AlamofireImage or another similar framework in a real project
    if let url = user.pictureUrl, let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        userImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
    } else {
        userImageView.image = UIImage(named: "MainImage")
    }

    // set the texts to the labels
    firstnameLabel.text = user.firstname
    lastnameLabel.text = user.lastname
    emailLabel.text = user.email
    mobileLabel.text = user.mobile
}

}

let defaultValues = UserDefaults.standard




// Alamofire Code to updating struct
struct User: Equatable {

var firstname = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "first_name")
//var firstname: String
var lastname = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "last_name")
var email = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "email")
var mobile = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "mobile_number")
 // var pictureUrl = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: 
"profile_image_url")
var pictureUrl: URL?
}




func ==(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
return lhs.email == rhs.email
}
```

Comment: I would like to obtain clarification as to what providing me the URL will do?  The URL is useless to me, unfortunately there is no documentation on how this process works.  If there is, I am not familiar enough with it

Comment: It seems you are never setting the user's pictureUrl. I would also use AlamofireImage (see the comment in your code). And make sure you update the data in the row after you get the server's response